# CefBrowser not loading after deployment using wix

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Hi I am new to CefBrowser .
When executing the solution from visual studio then the browser is working fine. 
But after the development phase when i tried to load the Cef browser directly after deployment the browser is not loading .

The difference i found in the development and deployment stage is  **When running from VS CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe is running in the task manager** but its not running after the deployment .

Am i missing anything ? I have copied all the files from the debug folder too .

Arshad

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/63/NuGet/Readme.txt#L26

Comment: Make sure all the files are present after installation, sounds like your missing the unmanaged resources. Make sure VC++ is installed also

Comment: Hi @amaitland thanks for the reply I just tried executing the app from debug folder where all the file exists and the browser is not loading . If I run through vs it will run from the same debug folder and it’s working good that’s the issue so I don’t think I am missing any files

Comment: You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for testing purposes.

Comment: Yes I tried that too I am building a class library in that using cefsharp . It’s working good in vs and not visible in deployement . Am I missing anything in class library ?

Comment: Not enough information, I have no idea how you've setup your project.

Comment: Saying yes I tried that too is also pretty vague. List explicitly what you have tried and what has and hadn't worked.

Comment: It’s a class library project and I have designed a form with veg browser in it . That’s it when I run from vs the browser is working and when I directly run from the doll browser is not loading and I found that cefsharp.browsersuprosess is not getting started in task manager

Comment: Try setting an absolute path for http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_CefSettings_BrowserSubprocessPath.htm

Comment: @amaitland Thanks the Issue fixed after setting absolute path for the CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @amaitland for the help and suggestions.

Issue got solved after **Initializing the CEF browser** and setting the absolute path for **CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe**

```
if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
        {
            CefSettings cefSettings = new CefSettings();
            cefSettings.BrowserSubprocessPath = path; // **Path where the CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe exists**
            cefSettings.CachePath = "ChromiumBrowserControlCache";
            cefSettings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true;
          Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);
        }
```

Arshad